# Winforms chart OverflowException when value 1E+29 or greater

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

When I add a series to the Winforms chart with a value that is 1E+29 or greater, then I get:

```
"System.OverflowException" in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: It means the number is too large for the underlying datatype (presumably decimal)  If you cant change that use scaling/logarithm

Comment: A known error. The underlying data type is double, btw. Scale down your data! logarithmic axes will not help..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx